# How to count duplicate list in the 2d list in python

Tags: python

Given:

```
list1 = [[1,2,1,2,1],[1,2,1,1,1],[1,2,1,1,1],[1,2,1,1,1],[1,2,1,2,1],[1,2,1,2,1],[1,2,1,1,1]]
```

Output should be:

```
{[1,2,1,2,1] : 3, [1,2,1,1,1] : 4}
```

Already tried

```py
def getDuplicatesWithCount(listOfElems):
    dictOfElems = dict()
    for elem in listOfElems:
        if elem in dictOfElems:
            dictOfElems[elem] += 1
        else:
            dictOfElems[elem] = 1  
            
    dictOfElems = { key:value for key, value in dictOfElems.items() if value > 1 }
    return dictOfElems

dictOfElems = getDuplicatesWithCount(tuple(features))
print(dictOfElems)
```

but getting error as

```
TypeError                                 
Traceback (most recent call last)

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_15000/2333321210.py in <module>
     10     return dictOfElems

     11

     12 dictOfElems = getDuplicatesWithCount(tuple(features))

     13 print(dictOfElems)

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_15000/2333321210.py in getDuplicatesWithCount(listOfElems)

      2     dictOfElems = dict()

      3     for elem in listOfElems:

      4         if elem in dictOfElems:

      5             dictOfElems[elem] += 1

      6         else:

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a default dict to count ocurrences creating a dict for every subList:

```
list1 = [[1,2,1,2,1],
         [1,2,1,1,1],
         [1,2,1,1,1],
         [1,2,1,1,1],
         [1,2,1,2,1],
         [1,2,1,2,1],
         [1,2,1,1,1]]

from collections import defaultdict

count_dic= defaultdict(lambda : 0)

for el in list1:
    count_dic[tuple(el)] += 1

#{(1, 2, 1, 2, 1): 3, (1, 2, 1, 1, 1): 4})
```

Answer (score 0):

`list`'s can't be keys because they are mutable and thus not hashable. You can try turning them into `tuple`s instead.

```
def getDuplicatesWithCount(listOfElems):
    dictOfElems = dict()
    for elem in map(tuple, listOfElems):
        if elem in dictOfElems:
            dictOfElems[elem] += 1
        else:
            dictOfElems[elem] = 1  
            
    return { key:value for key, value in dictOfElems.items() if value > 1 }
```

Or use `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

list1 = [[1,2,1,2,1],[1,2,1,1,1],[1,2,1,1,1],[1,2,1,1,1],[1,2,1,2,1],[1,2,1,2,1],[1,2,1,1,1]]

result = {i: c for t, c in Counter(map(tuple, list1)).items() if c > 1}
```

Result:

```
{(1, 2, 1, 2, 1): 3, (1, 2, 1, 1, 1): 4}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `itertools.groupby` here, as long as you sort the list first.

```
from itertools import grouby

list1= [[1,2,1,2,1],[1,2,1,1,1],[1,2,1,1,1],[1,2,1,1,1],[1,2,1,2,1],[1,2,1,2,1],[1,2,1,1,1]]

result = {tuple(g):len(list(size)) for g,size in groupby(sorted(l, reverse=True))}
```

Output

```
{(1, 2, 1, 2, 1): 3, (1, 2, 1, 1, 1): 4}
```